# Windows 7 docker toolbox - dockerizing jenkins - failing to install plugins

Tags: docker, jenkins, windows-7, jenkins-plugins, docker-toolbox

## software:

- windows 7
- docker toolbox / virtualbox
- cmder

#### Create docker-machine

`$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox default`

#### Configure this - cmder - to enable access to docker commands

`$ @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i`

#### docker - pull latest jenkins from docker

`docker pull jenkins`

#### Run example jenkins container and volume jenkins-data

`docker run --name myJenkins1 -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home jenkins`

#### visit jenkins url in browser

`http://192.168.99.100:8080`

## login with admin password

- install default plugins (including pipeline)
- errors:

  SEVERE: Failed to install Docker Pipeline
  java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
          at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1893)
          at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1651)
          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
          at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to install docker-workflow plugin
          at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:874)
          at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:813)
          at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1889)

  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Docker Pipeline v1.17 failed to load.

  - Pipeline: Groovy v2.57 failed to load. Fix this plugin first.
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:626)
        at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:864)

Answer (score 0):

I cleared any cache previous jenkins

`docker system prune -a.`

Then tried again and this has installed - Jenkins 2.138.2. Seems to have worked now.
Maybe it was incompatible jenkins and plugins, or network issues.